# Visual Studio 2008 Bug - F10 not stepping through any code?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I go into debugging, normally when you hit a break point you can press f10 to continuously step through the code, but when I press f10, it does nothing and it highlights the file dropdown at the top as if im hitting the alt key.

another issue is when i try to move over variables and click the + to expand into them they just disappear... I have reset my personal settings to default and to a backup from awhile ago and i can't seem to figure out why this is happening or what to do to fix it.

Comment: it appears to be an issue with the project itself, I can step through other projects without any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with multiple projects having the option for starting to do nothing and wait for a request. somehow this was messing up my debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the update [kb957912](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912)  installed. That should solve the F10 issue

EDIT:
After browsing the net, I found this about the x64: [64 or 32 bit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=969). It says that for the x64 you need to install the [Remote Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=440ec902-3260-4cdc-b11a-6a9070a2aaab&displaylang=en).

I'm guessing this doesn't help much, but you can also give it a try.

Comment: im running windows 7 x64 and i installed the update and it didn't fix anything

Comment: I reformatted and it is still happening, if it helps F10 is pausing the debugger and hitting shift+f10 does a right click. Any ideas?

I am trying to reinstall that update and already have the remote debugger installed